# How to modify a dataframe nested inside a list without re-assignment

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

I have a list object that contains several elements. One element is a data frame that I wish to modify: I want to perform some operations such as column renaming and mutating new columns.

Although one simple way is to extract the nested data frame, modify it, and finally re-assign the output to the original parent list, I'd like to avoid such solution because it requires intermediate assignment.

### Example

**Data.** let's build a list of several data objects

```r
library(tibble)

my_list <- lst(letters, mtcars, co2, uspop, iris)
```

**Task.**

1. I want to modify `my_list$mtcars` to:

   - rename the `cyl` column
   - compute a new column that takes a square root of values in `mpg` column
2. I want to modify `my_list$iris` to:

   - select columns that start with `sepal`
   - rename them to lowercase

   and ultimately I expect to get back a list object that is identical to the original `my_list`, except for the changes I made for `mtcars` and `iris`.

**My attempt.** Right now, the only way I know to achieve this involves re-assignment:

```r
library(dplyr)

my_list$mtcars <-
  my_list$mtcars %>%
  rename("Number of cylinders" = cyl) %>%
  mutate(sqrt_of_mpg = sqrt(mpg))

my_list$iris <- 
  my_list$iris %>%
  select(starts_with("Sepal")) %>%
  rename_with(tolower)
```

---

**My question:** Given `my_list`, how could I point to a nested element by its name, specify which actions should happen to modify it, and get back the parent `my_list` with just those modifications?

I imagine some sort of a pipe that looks like this (just to get my general idea)

```r
## DEMO ##
my_list %>%
  update_element(which = "mtcars", what = rename, mutate) %>%
  update_element(which = "iris", what = select, rename)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `purrr`'s `modify_at` function

```
library(tidyverse)
my_list %>% 
  modify_at("mtcars", ~rename(.,"Number of cylinders" = cyl) %>% 
              mutate(sqrt_of_mpg = sqrt(mpg))) %>% 
  modify_at("iris", ~select(., starts_with("Sepal")) %>%
              rename_with(tolower))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `imap` which passes name along with data for each iteration but this is not closer to your general idea.

```
library(dplyr)

my_list <- purrr::imap(my_list, ~{
  if(.y == 'mtcars') 
    .x %>% rename("Number of cylinders" = cyl) %>%mutate(sqrt_of_mpg = sqrt(mpg))
  else if(.y == 'iris') 
    .x %>% select(starts_with("Sepal")) %>% rename_with(tolower)
  else .x
})
```